# How to perform query operation on another query result

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, query-performance

How to get **approved** , **unapproved** , **deleted** count from the below result using sql query.

```
SELECT approved,deleted_at,count(id)AS count FROM `payment_voucher` 
    WHERE company_id = 1 GROUP BY approved,deleted_at;
```

I'm attaching the above-queried result as an image.

[image]

> Desired output: Approved:**32** not_approved:**4** deleted:**7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (approved=1) AND (deleted_at IS NULL) THEN `count` END) approved,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (approved=0) AND (deleted_at IS NULL) THEN `count` END) not_approved,
       SUM(CASE WHEN deleted_at IS NOT NULL THEN `count` END) deleted
FROM (your subquery) source
```

Comment: thank you Akina, it worked

Comment: Please mark as the answer.